# HTML Element not being inserted

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, .net-core

I'm working on a .NET Core project for my company where work orders are loaded from our SQL database using Entity Framework, filtered and then displayed as markers on a map through Google Maps API for our installers.

We have two types of filters: one that gets included in an Ajax POST, and one that filters locally to decrease load times and performance issues. What I'm trying to do is load the local filter items (lists that are included in the response when calling the initial Ajax POST). If the list of filter items exceeds 5 items, I want them to collapse to only 5 items and insert an anchor which expands (utilizes jQuery's `toggle()`) showing the rest of the items in that list.

This is the excerpt from the JavaScript function which takes care of that:

```
                filterItems
                    .forEach((filterItem, i) => {
                        var localItem = '<label class="' + selectorContainerClass 
                            + ' selectorContainer" id="' + selectorContainerIdPrefix + filterItem.key 
                            + '"><input id="' + convertValToEng(filterItem.value) 
                            + '" type = "checkbox" class="filled-in navy" name="' + inputName 
                            + '" value="' + filterItem.key 
                            + '" onchange="localFilter(this, this.value)" /><span class="selector-value">' 
                            + filterItem.value
                            + '</span> &nbsp; <span id="' + paramName + 'Cnt__' + filterItem.key
                            + '" class="selector-count"></span></label ><br />';
                        
                        document.querySelector("#" + colId).insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', localItem);
                        
                        if (i >= 5) {
                            $("#" + colId + " #" + selectorContainerIdPrefix + filterItem.key).addClass("collapse");
                            $("#" + colId + " #" + selectorContainerIdPrefix + filterItem.key).toggle(100);
                            $("#" + colId + " #" + selectorContainerIdPrefix + filterItem.key + " + br").toggle(100);
                        }
                    });
                
                if (filterItems.length > 5) {
                    //TODO: Fix the bug here; the .filter-collapse element is not being inserted under local installers.
                    var newEl = '<a class="filter-collapse" onclick="toggleFilterExpand(false, this)";><i class="material-icons">expand_more</i></a>';
                    document.getElementById(colId).insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newEl);
                }
```

[image]

I should be getting a `newEl` inserted under the "Installer" column (8 installers, 3 of them not being displayed), but I'm not. I've tried jQuery's `after()` and `insertAfter()` methods, but neither of those worked. `newEl` is being generated for the "Area" column, as it should, but for the "Installer" column it's not.

I've also tried inserting the element manually through the console window with the exact same code and it works.

Would appreciate some help with this as I feel lost regarding this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: I can't see the problem from what you've shown here. The code where you do the insert (where you call `insertAdjacentHtml`) relies upon the two variables `colId` and `filterItem` and they're not being set in what you have shown. I strongly suspect that the issue is with one of those two variables. I would suggest setting a breakpoint using developer tools on that line of code to a) check that it is being run and your `filterItems` conditional works and b) that `colId` is what you think it is at that point.

Comment: I've checked with a simple console.log on all of the variables needed for the insert, all of it seems fine. I will insert a breakpoint and update you in a moment. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @ChrisM Hi, check my answer; was a stupid mistake on my part. Thanks for the input anyway.

Comment: Glad to see you were able to figure it out. We all make mistakes like that sometimes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a stupid mistake on my end where I was removing the element `newEl` from the all the other filter lists before inserting a new one to the currently iterated one.